# Compare two columns of one dataframe to one column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I have one dataframe as below:

| Id1 | Id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 |  |

The 2nd dataframe is:

| ID | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pears |
| 2 | Grapes |
| 3 | Orange |
| 4 | Banana |
| 5 | Apple |

How can I get the output like:

| Id1 | Id2 | Review |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | Banana |
| 2 | 5 | Apple |
| 3 |  | Orange |

So, basically I am trying to do a look up for Id2 (from dataframe 1) and get the comment from 2nd dataframe but if the Id2 (in first dataframe) is null then get the Id1 comment from 2nd dataframe.

Comment: maybe this can help [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: ohh....okay Sir **:)**

Comment: @AnuragDabas - I think is possible `merge` with preprocessing missing values

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace missing values in `Id2` by `Id1` and then mapping column by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by another `DataFrame`:

```
s = df2.set_index('ID')['Comment']

df1['Comment'] = df1['Id2'].fillna(df1['Id1']).map(s)
```

If there is multiple `ID` columns is possible forward filling missing values and selected last column, then mapping:

```
df1['Comment'] = df1.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].map(s)
```

Solution with `merge` is possible with helper column:

```
df1['ID'] = df1['Id2'].fillna(df1['Id1'])
#another idea
#df1['ID'] = df1.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
df = df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left')
```

Or:

```
df = df1.assign(ID = df1['Id2'].fillna(df1['Id1'])).merge(df2, on='ID', how='left')
```

Comment: @jeyrael Thanks for your comment. Even I thought of the same but is there any other way? I was going through solutions on the internet and was trying to do it with merge (read somewhere lookup could be done using merge).

Comment: @KamalenduNayek - Sure, it is also possible, added to answer. Only need some preprocessing for replace missing values.